Conditional expectation obtained with conditional survival function
Suppose we are trying to calcluate
$$
E(X\mid Y)
$$
for some random variables $ X$ and $Y$. Can the result be obtained by integrating the conditional survival function
$$
S(s) = P(X > s\mid Y).
$$
You can suppose that everything is well defined. I know that under the condtion that $X$ takes values in $(0, \infty)$ the normal expectation can be calculated in this way, but I'm not sure about the above case. Any help is appreciated.

What is the answer when $Y$ is a constant?
